# Matching optionally in expression with Python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have written the following regex to match human-readable time at the command-line:

```
^(?:(?:(?:(\d+)d\s*)?(\d+)h\s*)?(\d+)m\s*)?(\d+)s$
```

Using non-capturing strings, this regex matches "human-readable" time equally-well in the following formats:

```
1d 2h 3m 4s
1h 2m 3s
1m 2s
1s
```

...and...

```
1d2h3m4s
1h2m3s
1m2s
1s
```

In this regex, if I include a `minutes` value, I also have to include a `seconds` value. I.e., I can't simply provide `15m` or `1d3m`, I have to provide `15m0s` or `1d0h3m0s`.

Is it possible to extend a regex to match these latter two use cases? How? **Please note:** I'm not necessarily looking for a drop-in solution, but a pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

## Update

Just a brief update that I made awhile back - this is for regex in Python.

Comment: Which regex engine are you working with?

Comment: Apologies. I'm working with regex in Python. I was trying to ask it as a platform-agnostic question.

Comment: There is no language-agnostic regex, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
\A(?=\S)(?:\d+d)?(?:\h*\d+h)?(?:\h*\d+m)?(?:\h*\d+s)?\z
```

The approach is to make all element optional. The lookahead at the begining ensures that there is at least a character that is not a space. *(in other words, it ensures that there is at least one element)*

Comment: why you use (?=\S) and not use (?=\S\S)

Comment: @walidtoumi: because testing two characters is useless, only one is necessary.

Comment: But the minimum is 1digit + 1letter (ex: 1s) ?

Comment: @walidtoumi:Indeed, but it doesn't matter, because once you know that there is at least one non-space character, you know that there is at least one group (whatever, the length of the group). The goal of the lookahead is only to check that the string is not empty since each group is optional. Its goal is not to test the length of the string but only to check that one group is present.

Comment: I played with this one. In Python, I wrote it as follows: `^(?=\S)(?:(?P<d>\d+)d\s*)?(?:(?P<h>\d+)h\s*)?(?:(?P<m>\d+)m\s*)?(?:(?P<s>\d+)s\s*)?$`. It matches all possible combinations of `day/hour/minute/second` that I came up with, [like so](http://regex101.com/r/iX5xR2/29). Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the `\h` _horizontal whitespace_ escape sequence is supported by Python (although not tagged as such, the target platform here is Python - see comments on question). Also, the orig regex captures the days, hours, minutes and seconds into `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and `$4`. Otherwise looks good to me.

Comment: @ridgerunner: `\h` isn't indeed supported by the re module of Python (but available in the regex module). As you notice it, the question isn't tagged for this language, however `\s` *(as I have written in my original answer)* is more widely supported but less constrictive. About the capture groups, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Rather that maintaining that regular expression and trying to tweak it I would suggest greatly simplifying your regex to this:

```
/ *(\d+)([dhms])/gm
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oU6hV1/1)

As you can see it matches all your current and proposed strings. You can then post-process both captured groups in your code.

Answer (score 1):

your seconds files is not optional.there is no ? after it.so all fields not containg s will fail.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iX5xR2/28

I have applied question mark.

Comment: Well, shucks. You mean it's that easy? I would have sworn I attempted *exactly* that regex without success. Just for the record (and future reference), the regex you threw out there was: `^(?:(?:(?:(\d+)d\s*)?(\d+)?h?\s*)?(\d+)m\s*)?((\d+)s)?$`. Thanks.

Comment: @DarthBob you were very close.i just debugged your regex.it was nice.just a small change :)

Comment: No...I was wrong. As I looked at it, there are some differences between your regex and the one I tried. Thanks again!

Comment: So...here's something odd for you. In this section of your regex: `(\d+)?h?\s*)?(\d+)m\s*)`, with the `?` after the `h`, `15m` matches with `1` in the hours position and `5` in the minutes position. If I remove the `?` from after the `h`, `15m` matches correctly, but `1d 5m` no longer matches.

Comment: @DarthBob you have grouped d and h together.they were together in your regex.so to make h optional have to add that

Comment: @DarthBob you can use your own regex.its working fine.i saw you have marked some other answer.but yours is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested groups:

```
/^(?:(?:(?:(\d+)d\s*)?(\d+)h\s*)?(\d+)m\s*)?(\d+)s$/g
```

The value for `d`, `h`, `m` and `s` are in groups 1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively.

[Here is a regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/oQ1wZ5/1)!